# PHP returns $_GET[] value is not defined after submit values using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, ajax

I have a javascript function that creates an XMLHttpRequest object or ActiveObject based on the browser being used living in a file called **ajax.js**

**HTML:** **user.php**

```
 <ul id="list-of-developers">
      <li class="list-title"><strong data-new-link="true">DEVELOPERS</strong>
      </li>                       
 </ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**: **ajax.js**

```
function ajaxObj2(meth, url, contype){
var xhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else 
{        
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open(meth, url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type",contype);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9000/");

return xhttp;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState==4 && x.status ==200)
    {
        return true;
    } 
}
```

In my user.php file which contains my html and the script tag including the **ajax.js** file in the head of the document.

Here is how the javascript connects with PHP (NB: This tag is located at the bottom of the document outside the body tag)

**JAVASCRIPT: user.php (inline)**

```
  <script>
    window.onload = function()
    {

        var u = "<?= $u ?>";

        var r = "<?= $user_role ?>";

        var x = ajaxObj2('GET', 'retrieveDevelopers.php','text/plain');
        x.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            alert("H u is: "+u+ " r is: "+r + " RESPONSE: " + x.responseText.trim());
            if(ajaxReturn(x) ==true)
            {
                alert("got here");
                var list_of_devs = document.getElementById("list-of-developers");
                console.log(list_of_devs);
                list_of_devs.innerHTML = x.responseText.trim();
            }
        }
        console.log(u);
        x.send("u="+u + "&r="+r);
    }  


</script>
```

**PHP: in retrieveDevelopers.php**

```
<?php 
      $x = $_GET["u"];
 $m = $_GET["r"];

if(isset($_GET["u"]))
{
    include_once("phpincludes/db_connx.php");
    //echo 
    $person= preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i','',$_GET["u"]);
    $person_sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID=(?) AND ACTIVATED=(?)";
    $person_params = array($person, 1);
    $person_options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED);
    $person_result = sqlsrv_query($db_connx, $person_sql,$person_params, $person_options);
    $person_state = sqlsrv_num_rows($person_result);

    if($person_state < 1)
    {
        echo "Failed to verify user";
        exit();
    }
    else 
    {
        echo("It Worked");
        exit();
    }

}

echo "failed";
exit();
?>
```

**I get errors "Notice: Undefined index: u in line 9"  and "Notice: Undefined index: r in 10"**

I don't understand why this is. The database connects without issue.
These files are all in the same folder except for the database connection script

**Filesystem:**

- /retrieveDevelopers.php
- /user.php
- /phpincludes.php/db_connx.php
- /script/ajax.js

**System Info**

```
Apache Version:2.4.17
PHP Version: 5.6.15 
MICROSOFT SQL SERVER 2012
Localhost: localhost:9000
```

Comment: Get is in the URL not in the send function. Your URL should look like `retrieveDevelopers.php?u="+u + "&r="+r`

Comment: take a look at the ajaxObj2() function which will result in the url value :"retrieveDevelopers.php?u=value&r=value" being created.

Comment: Just use your browser's debugger to find out if your ajaxObj2 sends required values. Then you will know where to look for errors, client or server side

Comment: I did that already and the response was (user.php:138 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:9000/retrieveDevelopers.php?"). There were no errors and all files loaded without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the var u and r try something like this

```
xhttp.open("GET", "retrieveDevelopers.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("u=value&u=value");
```

or

```
xhttp.open("GET", "retrieveDevelopers.php?u=value&r=value", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: u and r get sent in the line that says "x.send("u="+u + "&r="+r);" for the inline javascript.

Comment: also take a look at the ajaxObj2() function which will result in the url value :"retrieveDevelopers.php?u=value&r=value" of the open function being created.

Comment: it's strange, the error Undefined index: u in line 9" and "Notice: Undefined index: r in 10. Is because php is not getting u and r var.

Try this $x = $_GET[0]["u"];  echo $x;

Comment: sadly that still didn't work.. any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you try sending the vars in the web wrowser like http://localhost:9000/retrieveDevelopers.php?u=value1&r=value2

Comment: Yes I did. The same "failed" message gets echoed. Along with the error that u and r are undefined

Comment: Try using POST method instead GET